# Altering the default Django messages tag

Tags: python, html, django

By default, messages.success outputs `class='success'`. Either I need to overwrite this, remove it or append my tags to it to meet my needs. I've been unsuccessful in finding a way to overwrite and append to it. Here I've attempted to use `extra_tags`...

#### views.py

```
messages.success(request, '<a href="#">Item</a> Saved', extra_tags='html_safe alert alert-')
```

#### detail.html

I've tried adding `alert` before the `{{ message.tags }}`.

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class='messages'>
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class='{{ message.tags }}' role='alert'{% endif %}>{% if 'html_safe' in message.tags %}{{ message|safe }}{% else %}{{ message }}{% endif %}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

#### Bootstrap Alerts expects `class='alert alert-success'`

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.
</div>
```

#### HTML page source result

When all the code above is executed, the source code outputs the following. The only problem now is the space between `alert-` and `success`.

```
<ul class='messages'>
    <li class='html_safe alert alert- success' role='alert'><a href="#">Item</a> Saved</li>
</ul>
```

### End Goal! - Can anyone see a hacky or proper workaround here?

```
<li class="html_safe alert alert-success" role="alert"><a href="#">Item</a> Saved</li>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see why there is a reason to remove it. Unused CSS classes are not a terrible thing. Change it to:

```
messages.success(request, '<a href="#">Item</a> Saved', extra_tags='html_safe alert alert-success')
```

and don't worry about the extra `success` class. Have you checked Django's source code for this? Sometimes it gives hints as to extra `kwargs` that can be passed. The end result will be:

```
<li class="html_safe alert alert-success success" role="alert"><a href="#">Item</a> Saved</li>
```

It seems there are also ways to [configure the default message tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/#message-tags).

For example, in your `settings.py`:

```
from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages
MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.SUCCESS: 'alert alert-success',
}
```

But some Django projects and documentation may assume that the tag here is `success`, the default, so only change this if you are confident it is what you need. Otherwise, just add the Bootstrap class as an extra tag. Really, you shouldn't override Django's default just to suit Bootstrap. Either change Bootstrap's success class during [customization](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) to `success`, or just use both.

Comment: Thanks Jamie. I wasn't too keen on the idea of having unused CSS classes. I had a play with the 'configuring the default message tags' documentation yesterday, the default `success` class was still being included. But after reading your comment, I've added it to `settings.py` and boom, success! Awesome clarity... So I've tidied things up a lot by removed any tags within the html `li`. Added `html_safe` as the only `extra_tags` within `message.success`. And added `MESSAGE_TAGS = { messages.SUCCESS: 'alert alert-success' }` to `settings.py`.